# Хочу при обновлении страницы чтоб кнопка остался active

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const handleOpenShift = async () => {
    try {
      setOpenShift(true);
      setCloseShift(false);
      const dataOpen = {
        employeeId: userId,
        enterpriseId: id,
      };
      await openShiftWorker(dataOpen);
      toast.success(`Вы открыли смену ${format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')} ${format(new Date(), 'HH:mm')}.`);
    } catch (e) {
      setOpenShift(false);
      setCloseShift(true);

      if (e.response.status === 404) {
        toast.error(' Бариста не найден.');
      }
      if (e.response.status === 400) {
        toast.error(' Ошибка валидации.');
      }
      if (e.response.status === 403) {
        toast.error(' Нет доступа к данной операции.');
      }
      if (e.response.status === 500) {
        toast.error('Ошибка. ');
      }
    }
  };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня есть две кнопки, когда я нажимаю открыть смену , появляетса зеленая рамка, я хочу чтоб рамка была даже после обнавлении страницы

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: у меня есть две кнопки, когда я нажимаю открыть смену , появляетса зеленая рамка, я хочу чтоб рамка была даже после обнавлении страницы

Comment: @АрамГаспарян ну так добавь через JS класс ей. Можешь и условия прописать какие-то

Comment: какие ? Когда  открываю смену цвет меняется , но когда обновляю страницу возврашается default состояние .

Comment: Можете подсказать как состояние кнопки хранить в localStorege потом получить

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```js
  import {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
let [active, setActive] = useState((localStorage.getItem('active')) == 'true');


let activaHandler = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('active', !active)
  setActive(!active);
}

  return (
<div className="App">
  <button className = {active ? 'active' : "btn1"}
  onClick = {activaHandler}>Button 1</button>

  <button className = "btn2">Button 2</button>
</div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```